# 401 Running VBScript as scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, http-error-401.2

I setup a scheudled task on Windows Server 2008 to run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe //b //nologo D:\WebSites\MySite\Scripts\UpdateCache.vbs
```

The VBScript being run makes a simple GET request:

```
Dim o 
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
o.open "GET", "http://.../UpdateCache", False 
o.send
```

When I check the IIS logs after this runs, it always results in a 401.  The user running the scheduled task has read/write/modify access to the website folder and can access it through IE.  Any idea why I might be getting the 401 when running this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you receive a 401.2 is because the XMLHTTP request object doesn't supply credentials. You can do that in the `open`-method:

```
o.open "GET", "http://.../UpdateCache", False, username, password
```

Comment: That makes sense, but even after supplying credentials I'm still getting denied.